# What is wrong with Unetbootin? cannot install it anymore in Focal Fossa?

Tags: unetbootin

I have Ubuntu Focal Fossa.

I cannot install Unetbootin and use it as i've always used it in the past.

This is what I've [tried](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa

sudo apt-get update
```

And when I try: `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`

This happens:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unetbootin : Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: extlinux but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: unetbootin-translations but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: gksu but it is not installable or
                          kdesudo but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### None held packages either

I've tried `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` and there is none held packages. In this case, the output says that there are packages that ***are not installable*** (?).

### If I try using the UI, I get another error:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @karel. I've edited the question, because I don't think is a related issue. The output says that there are packages that are not installable...

Comment: Unetbootin *should* work, but if you have problems with it, I suggest that you try a workaround: Use the Ubuntu **Startup Disk Creator**, **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) for the same typical purpose, to create a boot drive in a USB drive or memory card. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb) and links from it for more details.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks! Maybe a workaround is the best, I've been dwelling on this for quite some time now, quite a few days before decided to post the question here.
About the other comment about the broken packages. I'm reading it again just in case I missed something. I can only say about it that, even with 1 million views has none accepted answer. And anyway, that's a fallacy, because it could have been "viewed" by a zillion people and still not apply to me.

Comment: No problems here with that. Please show us `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. If your issue remains unresolved, then I've used [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) with good success rates.

Comment: Well, I've ended up using Etcher. It did work quickly and simple, as expected. Must confess that it feels somewhat like a defeat, because I'm used to unetbootin and don't like when something cannot work for a reason that I cannot understand. Anyway, I count' afford spending more time into making it work.